# Accessing control value fails due to TypeError: Cannot read property 'getView' of undefined

Tags: sapui5

I've created a checkbox and set its default value to `true`. on that checkbox select, even I can get the value of that checkbox, either it's checked or not.
But from other methods in controller, how I can get the value? I tried different ways but still unable to get value.

```js
onChangeCheckbox: function(event){
  var value = this.byId("chkMyTest").getSelected();
}
```

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'byId' of undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I call the attach / detach events with a named function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55471384/how-can-i-call-the-attach-detach-events-with-a-named-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using XML views, then it should be:

```js
var value = this.byId("chkMyTest").getSelected();
```

Where **`this` refers to your controller.**

Comment: I used that one but it throw error " Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getView' of undefined(…) "

Comment: I found the solution , just did as var that = this , and than i used that.getView().byId().

Answer (score 2):

If this method is getting called by check-box, check-box will trigger event. So you can use event instead of 'this' to get value. You don't have to bother about this.byId() or this.getView().byId

You can do it like following example

```
onChangeCheckbox:function(event){
        var value = event.getSource().getSelected();
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

View :  CheckBox id="ch1" text="Option a" select="onchechSelectValue" name ="checkbox1"

Controller:

```
onchechSelectValue : function(oEvent){
            var chk1  = oEvent.getSource().getvalue();  //return checkbox name
//          or
           var chk1 = oEvent.getSource().getText(); // return text value


        }
```

You can also use 
this.getView().byId("ch1").getName(); or
this.getView().byId("ch1").getText();