# How can I call the attach / detach events with a named function?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a function which needs to attach and detach a handler to the event "requestCompleted" of the OData model to get the URL from the header in order to download the data as an Excel file.

```js
onClickAction: function (oEvent) {
    var model = this.getView().getModel();
    model.attachRequestCompleted(this.downloadODataAsExcel);
    var btnGo = this.getView().byId("btn");
    btnGo.firePress();
    model.detachRequestCompleted(this.downloadODataAsExcel, this);
},

downloadODataAsExcel: function (evt) {
    var url;
    url = evt.getParameters() && evt.getParameters().url;
    url = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZService/" + url + "&$format=xlsx";
    sap.m.URLHelper.redirect(url, true);
},
```

I am trying to detach the event afterwards to prevent snowballing of the event which causes the file to download **n+1** times each time you click the download button.

---

**Update:** this is the code I ended up with

```js
onClickAction: function (oEvent) {
    var model = this.getView().getModel();
    model.attachRequestCompleted(this.downloadOdataAsExcel, this);
    var btnGo = this.getView().byId("btn");
    btnGo.firePress();
},

downloadODataAsExcel: function (evt) {
    var url;
    url = evt.getParameters() && evt.getParameters().url;
    url = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_SERVICE/" + url + "&$format=xlsx";
    sap.m.URLHelper.redirect(url, true);
    var model = this.getView().getModel();
    model.detachRequestCompleted(this.downloadODataAsExcel, this);
}
```

The detach needs to be within the function otherwise the listener will be detached before the `requestCompleted` event fires.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly attach and detach event handler in UI5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61589257/how-to-properly-attach-and-detach-event-handler-in-ui5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`model.attachRequestCompleted(this.downloadOdataAsExcel, this);`

And then try to access the 'evt' object.

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers can be attached and detached by passing the **same list of arguments** to the methods. For example:

```js
myModel.attachRequesCompleted(this.onRequestCompleted/*NO .bind*/, this); // Pass the oListener (this) as an argument instead
```

```js
myModel.detachRequestCompleted(this.onRequestCompleted/*NO .bind*/, this); // Same list of arguments
```

By "same list of arguments", I mean:

- Do **not** pass an anonymous function directly as the event handler. It's impossible to reference it later when trying to detach it.
- Do **not** pass the function directly using `.bind` because [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#:%7E:text=The%20bind()%20function%20creates%20a%20new%20bound%20function) creates a **new** function which, again, makes detaching it impossible.
- Pass the same `oListener` reference. From the API description:

  > The passed function **and** listener object must match the ones used for event registration. [(Source)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.Model#methods/detachRequestCompleted)

The same **applies also for all `attach*` / `detach*` methods generated by the ManagedObject.**

In your case, the handler couldn't be detached because the listener object, when attaching the handler, was `undefined` instead of `this`.

---

Alternatively, [`attachEventOnce`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.EventProvider#methods/attachEventOnce) can be also used.

```
myModel.attachEventOnce("requestCompleted", this.onRequestCompleted, this);
```

Once the handler is called, it's detached automatically.

Comment: Justa question, what is the purpose use of attachRequestCompleted, detach and attachEventOnce?

Comment: @Jüngealles Just to be clear: are you asking particularly about the `requestCompleted` event? Or is the question about attaching and detaching events in general?

Comment: uuumm, if its okay i want to know more about all these things ^^

Comment: @Jüngealles Ok :) Well, `requestCompleted` is a very generic event provided by the base model. Its use case depends strongly on the model type and how developers approach their problem solving. I'm afraid I can't give a definitive answer to that. One example is shown in the question. I've personally never used it productively. But it's surely helpful if someone wants to do something every time a request is completed (no matter how the request ended).

Comment: @Jüngealles The `.attach*` and `.detach*` methods are available in all models, controls, etc. since they're all extended from [`sap.ui.base.EventProvider`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.EventProvider). When assigning an event handler declaratively (e.g. `press=".onPress"` in XML view), then the framework calls _.attach<EventName>_ internally. Again, there is no clear "purpose" of `attachEvent` since the method is quite generic.

Comment: @Jüngealles The `.detach*` method is, however, very important to avoid memory leak or calling on destroyed object accidentally. Whenever you're attaching event handlers (e.g. when using ResizeHandler, Router, etc.), keep in mind to remove them as well whenever they're no longer needed. For example in `onExit` (in Controller) or in `exit` (in Control development) which is called before the framework removes the object from the registry.

Comment: thanks, well i also never saw it or use this type of events/methods ^^ thats why this question. But thanks that was really helpful